# Visual Studio - vb console application. my program keepr crashing with code 0 and i dont know what to do

Tags: visual-studio

im using console. ive written code its for my exam and im not very good at it but ive tried and no matter what i do i cant get the program to stop crashing. it keeps crashing at code 0 and im really frustrated please help me ive attached the code below

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim discount As Integer = 0
    Dim freetickets As Integer = 0
    Dim estimatedcost As Integer = 0
    Dim totalstudents As Integer = 0
    Dim coachcost As Integer = 550
    Dim entryticket As Integer = 30
    Dim name(45) As String
    Dim paidstatus(45) As Boolean
    Dim studentspaid As Integer = 0
    Dim totalcost As Integer = 0
    Dim collectedcost As Integer = 0
    Dim finalcost As Integer = 0

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name")
    name(45) = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("has the student paid? (true/false)")
    paidstatus(45) = Console.ReadLine()

    If paidstatus(45) = True Then
        studentspaid = studentspaid + 1
        totalstudents = totalstudents + 1

    ElseIf paidstatus(45) = False Then
        totalstudents = totalstudents + 1
    End If

    totalcost = (totalstudents * 30) + (550 / totalstudents)

    If totalstudents = 45 Then



        If studentspaid = 10 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If


        If studentspaid = 20 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If



        If studentspaid = 30 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If


        If studentspaid = 40 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If



        collectedcost = (studentspaid * 30) + (550 / studentspaid)
        discount = (freetickets * 30) - (550 / studentspaid)
        finalcost = totalcost - collectedcost - discount

        If finalcost > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("loss of")
            Console.WriteLine(-finalcost)
        End If

        If finalcost = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("broken even")
        End If

        If finalcost < 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("profit of")
            Console.WriteLine(finalcost)
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Can you try debug your code?

Comment: yeah i press strat debugging it runs the code does the first step and asks for the name then the second step if the student has paid or not. then after that input it crashes and displays the error message The program '[2040] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic - Ive written some code to loop a program 45 times and its not looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354978/visual-basic-ive-written-some-code-to-loop-a-program-45-times-and-its-not-loop)