# Visual Basic - Ive written some code to loop a program 45 times and its not looping

Tags: vb.net

the program is supposed to get 45 inputs and output whether money was lost gained or broken even. the program only takes one imput then ends. its not looping and im unsure what to do im not very good at code this is for an exam so sorry if its very basic and i don't understand

here is the code

```
Sub Main()

    Dim discount As Integer = 0
    Dim freetickets As Integer = 0
    Dim estimatedcost As Integer = 0
    Dim totalstudents As Integer = 0
    Dim coachcost As Integer = 550
    Dim entryticket As Integer = 30
    Dim name(44) As String
    Dim paidstatus(44) As Boolean
    Dim studentspaid As Integer = 0
    Dim totalcost As Integer = 0
    Dim collectedcost As Integer = 0
    Dim finalcost As Integer = 0

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name")
    name(44) = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("has the student paid? (true/false)")
    paidstatus(44) = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine())

    If paidstatus(44) = True Then
        studentspaid = studentspaid + 1
        totalstudents = totalstudents + 1

    ElseIf paidstatus(44) = False Then
        totalstudents = totalstudents + 1
    End If

    totalcost = (totalstudents * 30) + (550 / totalstudents)

    If totalstudents = 45 Then



        If studentspaid = 10 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If


        If studentspaid = 20 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If



        If studentspaid = 30 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If


        If studentspaid = 40 Then
            freetickets = freetickets + 1
        End If



        collectedcost = (studentspaid * 30) + (550 / studentspaid)
        discount = (freetickets * 30) - (550 / studentspaid)
        finalcost = totalcost - collectedcost - discount

        If finalcost > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("loss of")
            Console.WriteLine(-finalcost)
        End If

        If finalcost = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("broken even")
        End If

        If finalcost < 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("profit of")
            Console.WriteLine(finalcost)
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `For`, and `While` are used for loop structures in VBA. You have neither of these.

Comment: im really bad at this. could you help me correct this to make it work??...

Comment: show some effort, that's the only way to learn.

Comment: Also, this doesn't look like VBA code at all. This is VB.NET, a **completely** different thing.

Comment: The main thing you seem to be missing is a loop of any kind. Try reading the documentation on [For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx)

Comment: @julekgwa i spent hours writing this alone. i really need help like my teacher is bad

Comment: sorry @Mat'sMug i didnt realise thanks for correcting me

Comment: @Blackwood thanks mate will do.

Comment: if anyone does have the time id really appreciate if you could help me integrate the loops. but otherwise thanks for the inputs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should google "vb.net for loop"  and read about how loops work.  Here is an msdn article on it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

To apply the idea to your code - figure out which parts exactly should be repeating 45 times.  Then wrap that in a for loop, something like the following:

```
For i as integer = 0 to 44

    ... part to repeat

Next i
```

Now - inside the loop - you will need to use the arrays you are declaring with the index from the loop.

For example when you are referencing `paidstatus()` you are currently doing `mpaidstatus(44)` - that will probably need to change to be `paidstatus(i)` - so that you are referencing the current element of the array as you go through the loop 45 times.

So this answer is some hints for you.  I'm sorry if you are looking for someone to post your completed code for you - we won't really do that here.  But at least you have some hints now.  The rest is up to you.

Comment: no this was just perfect thank you so much. this is exactly what i needed i really appreciate this. thanks mate